# Firestore rules block creating the very first document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In this example, a new user can create only 2 documents.
To count user documents, I created another document with an array of documents names.
My Firestore Rule

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {//ALL DOCS

function isSignedIn() { return request.auth != null; }
function isValidUser(userId) { return request.auth.uid == userId; }   
  
function isPremium(){
    let user=get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
    return user.data.role=="premium"
 }
function isNotRestrictedinWarehouses(){
    let value=2;
    let warehouses=get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/settings/warehouses);
    return warehouses.data.warehouses_array.size() < value;
  }
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}// all blocked on start

match /users/{userId} {// USER DOCS

  match/{document=**}{
    allow read,update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId);
    }
   
  // warehouses
  match /warehouses/{document=**}{        
      allow read,update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId);
      //above is the same like allow write;
      allow create: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId) 
                    && (isPremium() || isNotRestrictedinWarehouses()); 
  }  
    match /warehouses/{warehouse}{        
      allow read,update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId);
      //above is the same like allow write;
      allow create: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId) 
                    && (isPremium() || isNotRestrictedinWarehouses()); 
  }
}
}
}
```

The rules works OK if there is at least one document (warehouse). I tested it.
Unfortunately, on very beginning there are no Warehouses and this rules block creating the first document. I tried to create sample warehouse after sing up, but the rules block as well. I tried to do something like this:

```js
allow create: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId) 
              && (isPremium() || isNotRestrictedinWarehouses()
              || !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/settings/warehouses));
```

But it is still blocked.
What I need is to create sample document and limit number of documents per new user.

Comment: It is normal that you write `match /warehouses/{warehouse}` implying `warehouses` is a colection, and then `get(/databases/.../settings/warehouses)` implying  `settings` is a colection and `warehouses` a document? And there are no rules for creating this `settings/warehouses` document, is that set by an admin?

Comment: for settings I have //ACCESS TO SETTINGS FOR ALL VALID USERS
            match /settings/{document=**} {
                allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId);                    
            } . I found another solution to myself by creating first documents using Firebase Functions but still I would like to know it:(

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Firestore Security Rules alone. You will need to maintain a document that has the count, and use that in your rules. You can read the document where you are storing the count as shown below (e.g.):

```
allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/settings/warehouses).data.count <= 2;
```